# Devforce 7.2.2 and databinding and Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devforce

My application is in Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.1, DevForce IdeaBlade 7.2.2 and IdeaBlade databinding 4.1.3.

On a form, I drop a windows form combo box. I place a windows binding source on the form and set the `DataSource` property to `DomainModel.Offce`.

I then place an IdeaBlade Control Binding manager on the form. In the CBM I drag the Office object to the existing bindings tab. I set the control to the `OfficeComboBox`. I click the `ListConverters` properties button and set the `ListSource` to the OfficeBS binding source and the display member to `OfficeName`. The value member is _Self.

Here is the appropriate info from the Designer file

```
 listConverter2.DisplayMember = "OfficeName";
 listConverter2.ListSource = this.OfficeBS;

 // 
 // OfficeBS
 // 
 this.OfficeBS.DataSource = typeof(DomainModel.Office);


this.MemberBM.Descriptors.Add(new IdeaBlade.UI.WinForms.ControlBindingDescriptor(this.OfficeComboBox, typeof(DomainModel.Member), "Office1", listConverter2));
```

In the Form.cs file In my Load method I have the following code

```
OfficeBS.DataSource = Repository.GetOffices();

GetOffices() returns an IEnumerable<Office>
```

After this I set the forms binding source

```
MemberBS.DataSource = currentMember;
```

`currentMember` is the member that is currently being edited.

When the program is run. The form displays, the current members information is displayed. The Office ComboBox has all the offices listed.

Here is the problem. The text box portion of the Office ComboBox is blank. It should show the members current office but it is empty.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Unrelated, but... `winforms + databinding + third party $$$ products`.. `Am I missing something simple here?` - you seem to be missing WPF...

Answer (score 0):

A response to this issue can be viewed on the [DevForce forum](http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=4660&PID=17422&title=databinders-and-comboboxes-in-devforce-2012-winclient-vs-2013).